# Инкапсулированная структура, зависящая от параметра шаблона класса

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++, вложенные-классы

Есть шаблонный класс. Внутри него объявлена структура. Члены этой структуры должны иметь тот же тип, что и параметр шаблона. Как правильно объявить структуру? Она тоже должна быть шаблонной? Или просто указать имя параметра внутри? По идее, для каждого экземпляра шаблона ведь должна быть своя структура. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
    struct data
    {
        T var1;
        T var2;
    };
};
```

Comment: Вы бы не привели для пояснения кусок кода - что вы хотите сделать? (Понятно, не компилирующегося, но проясняющего ситуацию..)

Comment: Если она объявлена внутри шаблона, то она уже является шаблонной. *"тот же тип, что и параметр шаблона"* - и что же препятствует использованию типу из параметра шаблона?

Comment: @user7860670, вот, я пример добавил. Это проканает?

Comment: И в чем проблема с кодом из примера?

Comment: *"Не вижу препятствий!" (с) Пан начальник тюрьмы*

Comment: @Harry, то есть это нормально? Или так делать нельзя?

Comment: Да все нормально.

Comment: @Harry, а можно ещё вопрос? Имеет ли значение куда я помещу объявление структуры (да и вообще любого пользовательского типа данных), в смысле уровня доступа public/private? Если она будет внутри public, то ведь всё равно, по идее, нельзя определить её переменные "снаружи" класса?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Опять я в комментарий не помещаюсь...
К вопросу о доступе - это уже второй вопрос, никакого отношения к конкретно шаблонам не имеющий.

Что вы понимаете под "определением" в данном случае? Обращение извне класса? Почему бы и нет:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    struct data
    {
        T var1;
        T var2;
    } var;

};

int main()
{
    MyClass<int> x;
    x.var.var1 = 5;
}
```

Или вы имеете в виду "определить" как привести тело функции-члена этой внутренней структуры? Тоже можно:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    struct data
    {
        T func();
        T var1;
        T var2;
    } var;

};

template <typename T>
T MyClass<T>::data::func()
{
    cout << "func()\n";
    return var1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MyClass<int> x;
    x.var.var1 = 5;
    x.var.func();
}
```

Словом, вы бы сформулировали вопрос поточнее...

Comment: Ага, я понял, т.е. можно и так сделать: MyClass<int>::data var;

Comment: Я думаю вопрос был о том, можно ли будет сделать так: `MyClass<int>::data my_var;` где-то в main например